# Inline cell formatting in Excel with Excel Object Model

Tags: .net, excel, ax

I have an excel table with inline formatting - only one word in the cell is **bold**, for example. When I read the cell value I get a plain text BSTR. How can I get the formatting?

I'm doing this in AX but I guess it's the same as in C# or anything else that uses the Excel Interop library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `Characters` property of the cell.  Referenced as
 `expression.Characters(Start, Length)`

eg `Range("A1").Characters(3,1).Font.Bold` will tell if the third character is **Bold**

Comment: This seems to work in C#, but they didn't bother including it in AX/X++. Thanks.